# Css wildcard selector used to calculate padding

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a table where td's have classes that look like this:

indent-1, indent-2 ... indent-n

Is it possible to use this with wildcard selectors to set an incremental padding on the elements?

Pseudo code (because of my lack of understanding):

```
td[class^='indent'] {
   padding-left: (2*n)em
}
```

I have access to sass if that is required.

Comment: I don't think you can calculate some variable out of class name using CSS/CSS pre-processor. Can you use jQuery/js for that? Also, do you have known limit of indent-*n*?

Comment: SASS/LESS has mixins for this.

Comment: Could you give me some more information on these mixins? I am new to SASS so anything will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly I think you could use SASS to do something along these lines:

```
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  td.indent-#{$i} {
    padding-left: #{2*$i}em;
  }
}
```

Where you of course replace 10 with your number n. Of course this is only possible if you know the occuring 
numbers.

Comment: My problem is that I do not know the number of 'n'. I ended up using a javascript solution since it felt less hacky and produced a lot less code.

Comment: Im pretty sure that its your only option if you have no upper bound for n. Also less unnecessary code!